# How to create directory with name given by a prompt question with gulp

Tags: gulp, prompt

I would like to run a `gulpfile.js` task which asks in prompt the directory name to create it inside the build folder.

**Structure**

- gulfile.js
- build/

  - foo/ <-- directory name given by a question

**gulpfile task**

```
gulp.task( 'questions',  function( callback ) {
    return gulp.src('build')
        .pipe( prompt.prompt({
            type: 'input',
            name: 'dir_name',
            message: 'What is directory name ?'
        }, function( res ){
            //console.log(res.dir_name);
            //make directory called res.dir_name in build/
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks `gulp-prompt` package.
This example copy content `base` folder in `build` folder.

```
const prompt = require('gulp-prompt');

var my_dirname, project_build_path ;

gulp.task( 'questions',  function( callback ) {
    return gulp.src('./base/**/*')
        .pipe( prompt.prompt({
            type: 'input',
            name: 'dir_name',
            message: 'What is directory name ?'
        }, function( res ){
            my_dirname = res.dir_name;
            project_build_path = 'build/' + my_dirname;
            gulp.src( './base/**/*' ).pipe( gulp.dest( project_build_path ) );
        }));
});
```